# How to specify filename for ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using ACTION_SEND to send a file from the content provider in my app as an email attachment in GMail.  This works great, except that I can't programmatically specify the filename of the attachment.  When my URI is

content://my.documentcontentprovider/321

The filename of the attachment is 321.  321 is the document id.

I looked at the spec for Intent, and don't see an EXTRA_ key for specifying the filename.  The only workaround I could come up with is to append the filename to my URI:

content://my.documentcontentprovider/321/photo.jpg

It should work, but it seems a little hacky.  If someone has a better idea, please chime in.  Here's my code, in case it's useful:

```
    Intent sendDoc = new Intent();
    sendDoc.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendDoc.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, doc.name);
    sendDoc.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, DocumentContentProvider.getUri(doc.id));
    sendDoc.setType(doc.contentType);
    this.foldersFragment.startActivity(sendDoc);
```

Comment: It is hard to help without knowing what the DocumentContentProvider query will return. I assume it is not a Cursor. Is it a File object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to pass the filepath as `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM`. Well-designed ContentProviders expose filepaths in the `_DATA` columns.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  The problem was in my ContentProvider implementation, like you expected.  After implementing ContentProvider.query() to handle MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, GMail started setting the filename correctly.

Comment: "Well-designed ContentProviders expose filepaths in the _DATA column" -- first, not every stream served by a `ContentProvider` is represented by a file. Second, not every file is accessible by a third-party app. Google has been steering developers away from exposing "filepaths" to other apps for some time. I can't remember the last time I saw `_DATA` as a recommended pattern. `ContentProviders` like `FileProvider` serve up streams directly from a `Uri`.