# Constructing an on-the-fly Intent for a ShareActionProvider

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to use a `ShareActionProvider` to provide a button/submenu in my `ActionBar` to share a file that is generated from by my app's database. The file that will be generated depends on which tab the user is currently viewing. Since the data in the database may change, the file cannot be generated at the time the Activity is created, but must be created when the user requests to send it.

To this end, I have been following the [official Android guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider). Unfortunately, according to the guide,

> [...] if the action provider provides a submenu of actions, then your
>   activity does not receive a call to `onOptionsItemSelected()` when the
>   user opens the list or selects one of the submenu items.

There therefore appears to be no event that I can listen for to call `setShareIntent()` at the correct moment:

- `onOptionsItemSelected()` is not fired, unless the `ShareActionProvider` button is consigned to the overflow menu, which defeats the point of using it at all
- `onMenuItemClick()` is not fired, for unclear reasons
- `onShareTargetSelected()` cannot be used to modify the intent. Setting a new intent only applies to the next time the item is selected.

It seems that a key event is not covered by the API. How can I achieve the functionality I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The file that will be generated depends on which tab the user is currently viewing

Update the `Intent` when the user changes tabs.

> Since the data in the database may change, the file cannot be generated at the time the Activity is created, but must be created when the user requests to send it.

If this is truly a file (`EXTRA_STREAM`), use a `Uri` pointing to a `ContentProvider` of yours that will generate the file on demand.

If by "file" you mean just adjusting `EXTRA_TEXT`, do that as the user changes the data (e.g., `TextWatcher` on `EditText`).

Though I agree that `ShareActionProvider` ideally would have a "dynamic" mode where, when the user taps it, it asks you for the `Intent` at that point. I haven't seen any way to do that.

Comment: The difficulty is that the data may yet change after a tab has been selected. Knowing which tab is visible only switches between database tables - the records may still be edited.

If I construct an Intent pointing to a ContentProvider, will it wait to generate the file until the Intent is actually sent out to the chosen handler?

Comment: @Spinner: "If I construct an Intent pointing to a ContentProvider, will it wait to generate the file until the Intent is actually sent out to the chosen handler?" -- correct.Let's pretend that the file is a PDF that you're generating. Your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` basically has a "pointer" to the file in the form of the `Intent`. When the third-party app tries to use the file, your `ContentProvider` will be called with `openFile()`, and it is your job to write the file to a stream. Within reason, you can generate that file on the fly.

Comment: @Spinner: The "within reason" part is that the client might have some sort of timeout logic. If your file will take seconds or more to generate, I suspect that you'll have to pass on `ShareActionProvider`, look to fork it, see if anyone else has forked it that lets you generate the file, etc.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks. Downside: the created file's filename is set to the URI (without any file extension) which isn't ideal, but it'll suffice for now. Also, because `onCreateOptionsMenu()` may not have been called before `onTabSelected()` the `Activity`'s `ShareActionProvider` may not have been initialised by the first time `onTabSelected()` is fired, so I've instead had to create a field in the `Activity` to hold the `Intent`, and call `setShareIntent()` with this value within `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. If you see any shortcomings of this approach, I'd be grateful if you'd tell me.

Comment: @Spinner: "Downside: the created file's filename is set to the URI (without any file extension) which isn't ideal, but it'll suffice for now" -- you are welcome to have an extension on your `Uri`, AFAIK. With regards to the timing issue, that's not surprising, but you have a complex scenario. Complex scenarios are often complex. :-)

Comment: I had the impression, possibly incorrectly, that adding an extension was a bit messy (It's mentioned [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089494/how-to-specify-filename-for-action-send)). I currently pass the same URI to `openFile()` as I pass to `query()`, `insert()`, etc., since I considered it was simply another way of presenting the same data. Am I mistaken - should I generally aim to pass specific filename URIs to `openFile()`? I would have thought not, since I might want different filenames on different calls of `openFile()`.

Comment: @Spinner: "I had the impression, possibly incorrectly, that adding an extension was a bit messy" -- well, your `ContentProvider` could implement `OpenableColumns` and provide a `DISPLAY_NAME` that way, if you prefer. You are welcome to examine [the source code to `FileProvider`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.java) for an example of how this works. IMHO, a `Uri` is either for a stream (and then `query()` is used for `OpenableColumns`) or it is not. A `Uri` is not somehow both simultaneously.

Comment: @Spinner: This ties into a topic that I just [blogged about](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). The question and answer that you linked to are for the legacy `_DATA` pattern. Having openable `Uri` values is while `FileProvider` and the Storage Access Framework do, and there is no particular limitation on what the `Uri` looks like (e.g., ends in number, ends in filename, etc.).